# How to plot line connecting tops of bar plot in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a grouped bar plot and want to link the top of the bars with a kind of trend line.

On the picture I combined a barplot with a pointplot, but it did not lead to the desired result.

```
ax_line = fig_line.subplots()

ax_line = sns.barplot(x="Number of Agents", y="Duration",data=df, palette="Set1", ci=None, hue="Szenario")
ax_line = sns.pointplot(x="Anzahl Agenten", y="self.total_duration",hue="Szenario", data=df,palette="Set1", ci=None)


ax_line.set_ylabel("Duration",fontsize=15)
ax_line.set_xlabel("Number of Agents", fontsize=15)
```

[image]

Anybody got an idea?Unfortunately I am still a beginner in this area :D

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but maybe someone in the future will find it helpful:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

randoms = np.sort(np.random.randint(100, size=30))
df = pd.DataFrame(randoms.reshape(-1, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

hue = len(df.columns)
bar_idxs = np.arange(len(df)*(hue+1))
bar_idxs[::hue+1]

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    hue_idxs = bar_idxs[::hue+1] + i
    plt.bar(hue_idxs, df[col], width = 1, alpha=0.9)
    plt.plot(hue_idxs, df[col], '-o', label='line with marker')
plt.show()
```

Results:
[image]